# Filtering nested repeaters & paging correctly

Tags: asp.net, nested, repeater

I've got a `Repeater` displaying a list of Countries, and nested within this is another `Repeater` displaying categories, and nested within this is another `Repeater` displaying news articles.

This is working fine, however users should be able to enter a keyword and filter the search.

What is the best way of filtering this? Am I going to have to pass identical parameters to 3 different SQL Commands? I'd rather not..

Also, how can I then page this correctly so there are still `x` amount of articles per page?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store resultset from your DB in a `DataTable`, and then bind that table to the repeater you can filter the table by using `DataTable.Select()` method.